# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast (C language.)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Hi I am getting this error:'assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast'

what I have done is putting many values from different types of arrays into one pointer array. As a result I got this warning on the code which assign integer to my char pointer array.

this is my code:

```
int id[10] = {120, 121, 122, 123,124,125, 126, 127, 128,129 };
char *from[5] = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
char *to[5] = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
int date[5][3] = {{10,6,2018},{15,6,2018},{20,6,2018},{1,7,2018},{15,7,2018}};


char *flight[30];
int i = 2;


        int counter = 0;
        flight[0]="Flight ID:";
        flight[1]=  id[i]; //warning in this line.

        flight[2]=" From:";
        flight[3]=from[i];

        flight[4]=" to:";
        flight[5]=to[i];

        flight[6]=" Depart on:";
        flight[7]=date[i][0];//warning in this line.
        flight[8]="/";          
        flight[9]=date[i][1];   //warning in this line.
        flight[10]="/";                 
        flight[11]=date[i][2];  //warning in this line.
```

Comment: Fyi, you're not updating the value of `counter`, so you're just replacing the value of flight[1] over and over

Comment: Everywhere you try to copy a value from date to flight, you are trying to copy an int to a char*. What are you trying to do?

Comment: you are assigning pointer with the integer

Comment: What is this code really supposed to do? `id[i]` is the `int` 122, `flight[counter+1]` is `char*`. Why do you want to assign 122 to a pointer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?  Specifically, the lines you are (correctly) being warned about?

Comment: `flight` is an array of `char` pointers, `id[i]` is an `int`, you are assigning the incorrect types and that's what the compiler is complaining about

Comment: Are you expecting it to assign a formatted string, like `"122"`?

Comment: *I am getting this error* can confirm. *from different types of arrays* that's the reason. An array can only hold one type of things.

Comment: @Jose Fernando Lopez Fernandez thinks for your note. fixed it.

Comment: My question is how to store the values of id and other ints into my final array (flight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the warning because you're trying to assign an `int` value to a `char *`.  Those types are incompatible with each other.

Rather than being an array of `char *`, you should make `flight` an array of structs which will hold the various data that is a part of it:

```
struct flight {
    int id;
    char *from;
    char *to;
    int departMon;
    int departDay;
    int departYear;
};

struct flight flight[30];

...

    flight[counter].id = id[i];
    flight[counter].from = from[i];
    flight[counter].to = to[i];
    flight[counter].departMon=date[i][0];
    flight[counter].departDay=date[i][1];
    flight[counter].departYear=date[i][2];
    counter++;
```

Comment: You are right and I feel more comfortable with struct. however in the question I am limited to arrays.

Comment: @AL3MS What question are you referring to?

Comment: Store the values of id and other ints and from and to values into one place. so I can retrieve the information later. if, case , loops, arrays and strings are only allowed.